# SQL Server : combine values by group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data. I need to add a column with the final date on the status by ID. So, the final date for the first line will be the date of the second line.

Original data:

```
ID   | STATUS  |  DATE
-----+---------+-----------
1    | A       | 2020-01-03
1    | B       | 2020-01-07
1    | C       | 2020-01-14
2    | A       | 2020-01-04
```

Desired result:

```
ID   | STATUS  | DATE       | FINAL_DATE
-----+---------+------------+------------
1    | A       | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-07
1    | B       | 2020-01-07 | 2020-01-14
1    | C       | 2020-01-14 |
2    | A       | 2020-01-04 |
```

How implement it in SQL Server? Any idea?

Comment: do you want a new column in the table or just a select query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add a column to the table:

```
alter table original add column final_date date;

update o
    set final_date = new_final_date
    from (select o.*,
                 lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as new_final_date
          from original o
         ) o;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window function:

```
select *,
  lead(date) over(partition by id order by date) FINAL_DATE
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ac45cd7c7a1218db65a694c906bf1dd).
Results:

```
> ID | STATUS | DATE       | FINAL_DATE     
> -: | :----- | :--------- | :---------
>  1 | A      | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-07
>  1 | B      | 2020-01-07 | 2020-01-14
>  1 | C      | 2020-01-14 | null    
>  2 | A      | 2020-01-04 | null
```